# How do I understand pthread_create memory usage?

Tags: ubuntu, memory-leaks, pthreads

Here is the code sample

It creates a detached pthread

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *show_message( void *ptr )
{
    char *message;
    message = (char *) ptr;
    printf("[%s] start\n", message);
    int x = 3;
    for(x = 3 ; x > 0 ; --x){
        printf("%s \n", message);
        sleep(2);
    }
    printf("[%s] end\n", message);
}

int create_thread(char *message)
{
    pthread_attr_t att;
    pthread_attr_init(&att);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&att, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, &att, show_message, (void*)message);

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    sleep(3);

    create_thread("Thread 1");

    while(1) {};

    return 0;
}
```

---

Valgrind result shows no leaks

==9872== HEAP SUMMARY:

==9872==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==9872==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,296 bytes allocated

==9872==

==9872== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

---

but I read /proc/[pid]/statm

Size and Resident get higher

```
[~] $ while [ 1 ]; do cat /proc/`pidof pthread_example`/statm; sleep 2; done
```

1596 218 198 1 0 50 0            <- run

1596 218 198 1 0 50 0

20062 218 198 1 0 18516 0        <- [Thread 1] start

20062 218 198 1 0 18516 0

20062 218 198 1 0 18516 0

20062 299 278 1 0 18516 0        <- [Thread 1] end

20062 299 278 1 0 18516 0

---

why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking why the process memory size doesn't reduce when memory is freed, that's actually quite simple.

When extra memory is needed in the process (such as when you try to allocate some memory but there's not enough there to give you), the process requests more memory from the operating system.

However, when you *free* that memory, there's no requirement that it actually be realeased back to the OS, far more likely is that it will be needed again at some point so the process keeps it around just in case.

Think of it this way:

```
    A              B             C
+--------+     +--------+    +--------+
| Memory |     | Memory |    | Memory |
|    for | <-> |     in | <- |     in |
|    you |     |   heap |    |     OS |
+--------+     +--------+    +--------+
```

It's likely that the memory flows *both* ways between `A` and `B` as you allocate and free it but it only flows *from* `C` to `B` as needed. Of course, when your process exits, whatever is being held in `B` will be returned.

Keep in mind this is a *conceptual* description, there's probably no *actual* memory coming out of the OS, more accurate would probably be that the OS just expands your address space to a larger size. The actual memory is doled out as needed by whatever virtual memory manager you have.

Comment: So ... does the process just keep it? If the process is idle for a while, is it supposed to reduce?

Comment: @YuTse, it depends entirely on how the interface is designed between the OS and process. But, with modern VM, any memory you're not using will probably get swapped out eventually so that it doesn't impose on physical memory. It costs very little to keep the bookkeeping information around. In the old days when whole processes (especially big ones that don't release their memory) were swapped in and out, it may have had an effect. But paging (swapping out small sections of processes) removes that issue.